# Yii join two models

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I've got two mysql tables:
1. prices
2. details

**Table Prices**

```
ID  |  DATE     | CODE |  PRICE
1   |2014-01-01 | AAA1 | 90.123
2   |2014-01-01 | AAB1 | 50.113
3   |2014-01-01 | AAC1 | 48.621
4   |2014-01-02 | AAA1 | 91.123
5   |2014-01-02 | AAB1 | 51.113
6   |2014-01-02 | AAC1 | 41.621
```

**Table Details**

```
CODE | NAME   | DESCRIPTION
AAA1 | andria | A very good...
AAB1 | anasta | A very good...
AAC1 | simple | A very good...
```

**Models:**

**Prices**

```
public function relations(){
        return array(
            'code' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'details', 'code'),
        );
    }
```

**Details**

```
public function relations(){
        return array(
            'code' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'prices', 'code'),
        );
    }
```

Here's the SQL code I want to execute:

```
SELECT * FROM prices a 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM details) b
WHERE a.DATE=(SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM prices) AND a.code = b.code
```

My controllers:

```
$prices=new CActiveDataProvider('prices', array(
                'criteria'=>new CDbCriteria (array(
                    'select'=>'code,date,close',
                    'condition'=>'date=(SELECT MAX(date) FROM prices)'
                )),
            ));

$this->render('index',array(
                'prices'=>$prices
            ));
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php 
    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$prices,
    'template'=>"{items}",
    'enablePagination' => false,
    'columns'=>array(
        array('name'=>'code', 'header'=>'Code'),
        array('name'=>'name', 'header'=>'Name'),
        array('name'=>'close', 'header'=>'Close'),
    ),
)); ?>
```

With this controller commands, I can get the data from table prices, but I can't get the data from table details.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `with` part of the criteria: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#with-detail

I think your code should look something like this (untested):

```
$prices=new CActiveDataProvider('prices', array(
            'criteria'=>new CDbCriteria (array(
                'select'=>'code,date,close',
                'with' => 'details',
                'condition'=>'date=(SELECT MAX(date) FROM prices)'
            )),
        ));
```

Comment: Relation "details" is not defined in active record class "prices". any idea what went wrong?

Comment: Nope, but you can add the relationship yourself ofcourse.

Answer (score 1):

you already have reliation in Model. So do query like this in your controller

```
$prices=new CActiveDataProvider('prices', array(
        'criteria'=>new CDbCriteria (array(
            'condition'=>'date=(SELECT MAX(date) FROM prices)'
        )),
    ));
```

In View just use

```
$data->code->name
$data->code->description
```

Comment: If I use your code, I can get the code, price and date (from prices table) not from the details table. The name just become an empty column.

Comment: in your Model reliation must be like this 
  `return array(
   'code'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Prices', 'code')
  );`

Comment: which model are you talking about? the prices or the details? You can see my model relations from above.

Comment: @user3054630 can u please help me i also have same issue i have defined relationship in model but failed to display values in my form using foreign key relationships

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I change:

**index.php**

```
<?php 
    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$prices,
    'template'=>"{items}",
    'enablePagination' => false,
    'columns'=>array(
        array('name'=>'code', 'header'=>'Code'),
        array('name'=>'name', 'header'=>'Name', 'value'=>'$data->details->name'),
        array('name'=>'close', 'header'=>'Close'),
    ),
)); ?>
```

**Models Prices**

```
public function relations(){
        return array(
            'details' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Stocks_details', 'code'),
        );
    }
```